# Contador Numérico

Tags: c++, arduino, contador

Devo criar um programa que comande um hardware no qual tenho ligados em 3 portas diferentes do arduino um circuito contendo 3 leds. O programa deve fazer ascender esses leds em ordem binaria.

Tenho duas funções prontas, a primeira função `"incrementaDigito"` tem 4 variáveis; `"base"` que refere-se a base no qual estamos operando, neste exemplo uma base binaria, o vetor `"numero[]"`, um vetor com enésimas posições que será utilizado para armazenar o valor binário, `"k"` é a variável usada para atualizar o algarismo de cada posição desse valor binário armazenado no vetor, e `"n"` é o número de elementos que o vetor `"número[]"` irá conter. Esta função tem como função atualizar cada posição do vetor em ordem crescente, enquanto o `"numero"` for menor do que a `"base"` há um incremento na variável `"k"` e é retornado um resultado falso. A partir do momento em que o "numero" for igual a base, a função atribui zero a `"k"` e retorna um resultado verdadeiro.

A função `"incrementaNumero"` tem as variáveis `"base"`, `"numero"`, `"n"`. define-se a variável `"k"` como função de `"n"`, o numero de elementos no vetor `"numero[]"`. Se a função anterior retornar falso nada acontece, quando retornar verdadeiro há um decremento em k.

Tenho que terminar o Loop e o Setup do meu programa, e fazer a documentação, podem me ajudar a relacionar essas funções para que eu consiga terminar?

```
//CÓDIGO

#define DELAY 400
#define NUMERO[0,0,0]
#define BASE 2
# define N 3
bool incrementaDigito (unsigned base, unsigned numero[], unsigned k, unsigned n){
  if (numero < base){
    numero[k]++;
    return false;
  }
  else{
    numero [k] =0;
    return true;
  }
}
void incrementaNumero (unsigned base, unsigned numero[], unsigned n){
  unsigned k = n-1;
  do{
    if(incrementaDigito(base, numero, k, n)==false) break;
    else k--;
  }
  while(k>=0);
}  

int ledPin1 = 11;
int ledPin2 = 12;
int ledPin3 = 13;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin1 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3 , OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned numero[];
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
      for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
        if(k==1){
          j++;
          k=0;}
          if(j==1){
            i++;
            j=0;
            k=0;}
              if(i==1){
                i=0;
                j=0;
                k=0;}
      }
    }
  }

  digitalWrite(ledPin1, );
  digitalWrite(ledPin2, );
  digitalWrite(ledPin3, );

  delay(DELAY);
}
```

[image: Segue imagem do meu circuito]

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de toda essa parafernália para construir seu contador!

Uma simples solução seria utilizar o *operador bitwise* `&` para verificar de forma independente os 3 *bits* menos significativos de `n`, por exemplo:

```
digitalWrite( ledPin1, n & 1 ); /* Bit Menos significativo (LSB) */
digitalWrite( ledPin2, n & 2 );
digitalWrite( ledPin3, n & 4 ); /* Bit Mais significativo (MSB) */
```

Segue um código capaz de implementar um contador binário de 3 bits usando 3 LEDs:

```
#define DELAY 1000

const int PIN_LED_Q0 = 11;   /* Bit Menos significativo (LSB) */
const int PIN_LED_Q1 = 12;
const int PIN_LED_Q2 = 13;   /* Bit Mais significativo (MSB) */

void setup()
{
  pinMode(PIN_LED_Q0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_LED_Q1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_LED_Q2, OUTPUT);
}

void exibir( byte n )
{
  digitalWrite( PIN_LED_Q0, n & 1 );
  digitalWrite( PIN_LED_Q1, n & 2 );
  digitalWrite( PIN_LED_Q2, n & 4 );
}

void loop()
{
  for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
  {
    exibir( i );
    delay(DELAY);
  }
}
```